# ul and block elements floated left

Tags: html, css-float, html-lists

My question is: Is the following behaviour defined or is it a bug?

I have seen answers with various workarounds, but not about the behaviour itself.

By default the bullets for each <li> against a block which is floated left get rendered inside the block instead of to the right. However, this is how I would expect it to render (space between the block and the bullets until the <li>s drop below the element, then the same amount of space between the edge of the parent block and the bullets):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .my_div  {
            float: left;
            background-color: #CCF;
            /* To push <li>s out */
            margin-right: 25px;
        }
        .my_ul   {
            /* Consistency across all browsers */
            padding-left: 25px;
            /* Fix for Opera only */
            list-style-position: inside;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my_div">Some text<br>Second line</div>
    <ul class="my_ul">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Try removing the `.my_ul` style and `margin-right` and view again. I expected that it would render the same way but it doesn't. It works the same in all browsers that I have tested it on (Opera 12, Firefox 17, Chrome 23, Internet Explorer 8, Safari 5).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [sample](http://jsbin.com/egojut/1) and [code](http://jsbin.com/egojut/1/edit).
Just I provided **margin-left** for the `<ul>` element. I aligned block is left and list item in right. Is this your wants?

Comment: Thanks for posting! No, I want the bullets on the third and forth lines to be aligned under the light blue box. If you use my example code it is exactly how I want it to behave, I just thought that I shouldn't need so much CSS (i.e. that only the `float` and `background-color` should be needed). If this is desirable behaviour can someone explain why because when I saw it I thought it was a bug (why would you want your bullets inside a floated element by default?).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be as follows:

```
ul {
    margin-left:0; list-style-type:none;
}
ul li:before{
    content:"\25cf\00A0\00A0\00A0";
}
```